# what is the meaning these below mentioned 5 thats?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The teacher said that that that that that boy used was wrong.
Please, briefly explain above stated sentence.

Comment: It's wrongly punctuated.

Comment: @Edwin: it seems to me any of the second + third, the third alone, or the third + fourth instances of ***that*** could validly be enclosed in quotes, so it's also "ambiguous".

Comment: [The teacher said that] that "that" (the word) that (which) [that boy over there] used...  No-one would really use a sentence like this, it's just a humorous example of how grammar can sometimes be confusing.